# PayPal express useraction not working when legacy fallback happens

Tags: paypal

**Trying to Accomplish:**
In checking out using PayPal Express lightbox pops up and displays "Pay Now." I bypass the order review page and send user to an order confirmation page that completes payment and displays confirmation.

**Problem**: PayPal will sometimes display lightbox overlay with "Pay Now" and sometimes redirect the whole page to a legacy paypal page that shows "Continue - You're almost done. You will confirm your payment on New Owner's Test Store."

**Why this is a problem?**
They get sent to an order confirmation page that bypasses an order review page, it would look strange if they click continue and they are immediately transferred to a payment success order confirmation page.

**Technical details:**
URL they are sent to after handshake for token-https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?useraction=commit&token=&useraction=commit#/checkout/login
Fallback URL they sometimes get redirected to-https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/fallback?product=ec&reason=hermes_to_legacy&fallback=1&incontext=1&token=&useraction=commit
*-The fallback URL shows users 'continue' even though I selected commit (ie.pay now)*

**What I don't know how to do:**
I don't know how I can create a catch on the return URL in the response I get from PayPal so I know whether or not the user was shown a "Pay Now" button or a "Continue - You're almost done. You will confirm your payment on New Owner's Test Store." If they were shown "Pay Now", I want it to show a payment confirmation page, if they are shown "Continue" I want to not call the DoExpressCheckoutPayment and instead show a "Complete Order" button which will then call the DoExpressCheckoutPayment and show them then payment confirmation.

*Note: I am working in the Sandbox.*